# Will a completely removed cat whisker grow back?

Tags: zoology, sensation

I just accidentally pulled out, while playing, my cat's whisker entirely, follicle and all. I feel terrible as I know she is a kitten and whiskers are rooted deep in a place rich in nerves. I'm wondering if the whisker will grow back and if it will cause a lot of pain as it regrows.

Comment: If you're concerned about the pain aspect, approach your vet, as I'm sure they would be able to tell you how to treat it.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that yes, they will grow back. Cats do regularly shed their whiskers and grow them back in time ([reference](http://avetsguidetolife.blogspot.in/2011/07/do-cat-whiskers-regrow.html)). The thing is that if damage has been done to the root of the whisker, it may grow back in an irregular manner ([reference](http://pets.thenest.com/cat-whiskers-grow-back-pulled-out-11482.html)). Wish for the best and by now I think the whisker should be back just fine.